# ELAN9008:00 04F3:2D55

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, keyboard-backlight

I recently purchased a Asus Zenbook Duo 14, running a dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04.  Today I received a warning notification that the keyboard backlight was low on power and would soon stop, the warning code being 2D55.  When going into Ubuntu's settings, under battery, then under devices, it's listed as ELAN9008:00 04F3:2D55 with 0% power.  My question is, is there a patch to fix this, or a driver that I am missing, or even a setting I have set incorrectly?

Comment: I have no Zenbook, but in Linux many things are just done by triggered scripts. I assume there is an ACPI message triggering this. Check the logfiles (`/var/log`) for more information. There is a ACPI config folder `/etc/acpi` maybe you find a hint and the script there.

Comment: I have the same error message. What does it mean? Did you fix it?